# Compare start Time in account state from context and current time of SYSVAR clock

Tags: sysvar

I have a condition like

let now = Clock::get()?.unix_timestamp as u64;
if now <= account.start_time {
// throw Error
}

So if the user send the start time from the front end and then it compare the start time (account.start_time) to  the cluster time (now). So there is always the 15 to 20 second difference of users start time and cluster time and it throw the error in a wrong condition.
So How can I sync with as to remove this 15 to 20 second difference.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to control two independent walltime sources like this.  Instead of letting the user submit the `start_time` from the frontend, use a transaction to set it from the clock sysvar

Comment: Yes I can do this like, but actually I want to start the stream of some amount like of start time = 05:10:25 and according to the sysvar time I would set it like start time = 05:10:35, and then when I want to withdraw stream after 15 second so it might effect the stream amount because the cluster is changing some time ? How can I manage this ?